# Changing the style dynamically.

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to change the style / the theme of my report based on the User.
All my User have a UserGroup. My UserGroup has custom style.
All this information are in the DB.
UserStyle: ID | ID UserGroup | LOGO | Style 1 | Color 1 | ect..

I want change my report style with those informations. 
I know it is possible to give my item a style name. 
But Can i define it in the main report Code behind.

Bonus: Can I do this Only once for the Main Report?

Basically using Style Name as a CssClass.

Comment: have you thought about using a session, and JS with you CSS? so effectively I mean what you can possibly do is on login, your session starts so the user logs in. when they login, depending on the user e.g. lets say if the user "Admin" has a background colour of red, then you could, in js do something like .AddClass property to add in the class you want when the user logs in? OR maybe update the css depending on the user? it is possible for sure.

Comment: Im already handeling the Css in my master page at Page_Load.
I just have no idea how to apply css or style in general in a telerik report.
I know how to style a element but it will be just for this element i have 1 main report with 23 sub report. Its like 200+ element to manualy style. 
Iam looking for a generic way to handle the style/theme. 
And i would like to do it in code behind. Because 'stylename' ( the kindish css class ) does not accept expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 2. The Designer GUI

1. Design all your [style rules](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/style-using-styles-to-customize-reports)
2. Export them using.
   [Exporting and Reusing Style Sheets](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/style-exportingand-reusing-style-sheets)

You can bind them in your code behind , filtering on a parameter. 
Or just add them in your calling apps.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. The programmer solution

> If you have an aversion for the GUI, This is made for you !

The 1rst is the ***worst***, but the 1rst work around I came up with.

Style in a telerik report can be define in a [StyleRules](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/style-creating-style-rules).
In order to manage the theme based on the user you can use a ReportParameter.

```cs
Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule styleRule1 = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule();
styleRule1.Selectors.AddRange(new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.ISelector[] {
new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleSelector("MyStyle")});

if( reportParameter1.Value == "StyleUser1")
{
    styleRule1.Style.Padding.Left = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Point(2D);
    styleRule1.Style.Padding.Right = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Point(2D);
    styleRule1.Style.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    styleRule1.Style.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    styleRule1.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    styleRule1.Style.Font.Name = "Segoe UI";
}
else {
    //default style
}
```

You can add the Style name to you element from the designer or from the constructor.
this way:

```cs
this.textBox2.StyleName = "MyStyle";
```

You can create your style rules in the designer and only assign the style to the component in your initialise component.

```cs
if( reportParameter1.Value == "StyleUser1")
{
    this.textBox1.StyleName = "MyStyle";
    this.textBox2.StyleName = "MyStyle";
    this.textBox3.StyleName = "MyStyle";
}
else {
    //default style
}
```